# Problems placing the proper conditions in the 'else if' statements to perform query in Android

Tags: java, android, database, string, if-statement

I'm trying to change the values in the same String attribute in my application using else if statement but have been facing some problems so far. Till now i havent been able to change the values. Here's the significant part of my code. Any Suggestions?

```
protected void ScheduleOp1() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String VarMin = "-140 minute";

   db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " + view_Schedule1);
   db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " + view_Schedule1 + " " + " AS SELECT "
         + sBusDepart + "," + sBusArrival + "," + sBusDepartT + ","
         + sBusArrivalT + " FROM" + " " + fDepart + " " + "INNER JOIN" + " "
         + sBusSchedule + " " + "ON " + sBusSchedule + "." + sBusDate + "="
         + fDepart + "." + fDate + " " + "WHERE " + fDate + "= '" + fDate1
         + "'" + " " + "AND" + " " + sBusDepartT + " "
         + "= strftime('%H:%M', '" + fTime + "', '" + VarMin + "');");

   Cursor cur = fetchAllTodos();
   startManagingCursor(cur);

   if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
      Toast.makeText(
            getBaseContext(),
            cur.getString(0) + "  " + cur.getString(1) + "  "
                  + cur.getString(2) + "  " + cur.getString(3) + "\n",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } else if (cur.moveToFirst() == false) {
      VarMin = "-150 minute";
   } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

--Updated--

Here's an update of the code. What i'm trying to do is constantly change the value of 'VarMin' in order to perform a search through the view that i've created. the 'else' statement is for when there are absolutely no results found.

```
protected void ScheduleOp1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " +view_Schedule1);
        db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " +view_Schedule1+ " " +
                " AS SELECT " +sBusDepart+ "," +sBusArrival+ "," 
                +sBusDepartT+ "," +sBusArrivalT+ " FROM" + " "
                +fDepart+ " " + "INNER JOIN" + " " +sBusSchedule+ " " +
                "ON " +sBusSchedule+ "." +sBusDate+ "=" +fDepart+ "." 
                +fDate+ " " + "WHERE " +fDate+ "= '" +fDate1+"'"+" "+
                "AND" + " " +sBusDepartT+ " " + "= strftime('%H:%M', '" +fTime+ "', '" +VarMin+"');");





          Cursor cur = fetchAllTodos();
            startManagingCursor (cur);

            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {




                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), cur.getString(0)+ "  " +cur.getString(1)+ "  "
                 +cur.getString(2)+ "  " +cur.getString(3)+ "\n",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if (cur.moveToFirst() == false){
                VarMin = "-145 minute"; 
            }
            else if (cur.moveToFirst() == false){
                VarMin = "-150 minute";
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


    }




           //fetching records from database
         public  Cursor fetchAllTodos() {   
         return db.query(view_Schedule1, new String [] {sBusDepart, 
                 sBusArrival, sBusDepartT, sBusArrivalT }, null, null, null, null, null);
           }

    }
```

hope you guys can help me out.

--UPDATE --

Here is an update of the full code.

```
package sirtat.individualProject.PublicTransportationTimeScheduler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Toast;

import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class ScheduleActivity extends Activity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    TimePicker timePicker;
    DatePicker datePicker;


    int hour, minute;
    int yr, month, day;


    static String fDate1="DepartureDate";
    static String fDate2="DepartureDate";
    static String fTime="DEPART_TIME";
    static String fTime2="DEPART_TIME";

    public static final String view_Schedule1 = "ViewSchedule1";
    public static final String sBusArrival = "SBusArrivalLocation";
    public static final String sBusDepart = "SBusDepartLocation";
    public static final String sBusArrivalT = "SBusArrivalTime";
    public static final String sBusDepartT = "SBusDepartTime";
    public static final String fDepart = "FlightDeparture";
    public static final String sBusSchedule = "SkyBusSchedule";
    public static final String sBusDate = "SkyBusDate";
    public static final String fDate = "FlightDate";

    private int Min=140;
    private String getVarMin(){
        return "-"+Min+" " + "minute";
    }


    //private String VarMin = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.schedule_layout);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("PublicTransport2" , SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true); 



        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        //--GET THE CURRENT DATE--
        yr= today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        //--GET THE CURRENT TIME--
        hour = today.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minute = today.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);





        //--Button view--
                Button btnOp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOption1);
                btnOp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int year1 = datePicker.getYear();
                        int mnth1 = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
                        int dy1 = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                        int hr1 = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
                        int min1 = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

                        fDate1 = (pad(year1)) + ("-") + (pad(mnth1))
                             + ("-") + (pad(dy1));
                        fTime = (pad(hr1)) + (":") + (pad(min1));

                        ScheduleOp1();  
                            }
                    private Object pad(int b) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (b >= 10){
                            return String.valueOf(b);
                        }else{
                           return "0" + String.valueOf(b);
                        }


                    }
                   });  

                Button btnOp2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScheduleOption2);
                btnOp2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int year2 = datePicker.getYear();
                        int mnth2 = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
                        int dy2 = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                        int hr2 = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
                        int min2 = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

                        fDate2 = (pad2(year2)) + ("-") + (pad2(mnth2))
                             + ("-") + (pad2(dy2));
                            fTime2 = (pad2(hr2)) + (":") + (pad2(min2));

                            ScheduleOp2();



                    }


                    private Object pad2(int c) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (c >= 10){
                            return String.valueOf(c);
                        }else{
                           return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
                        }
                    }

                });

            }

    protected void ScheduleOp1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Cursor cur = null;
            boolean mustCont = true;
            while (mustCont){
                db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " +view_Schedule1);
                db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " +view_Schedule1+ " " +
                        " AS SELECT " +sBusDepart+ "," +sBusArrival+ "," 
                        +sBusDepartT+ "," +sBusArrivalT+ " FROM" + " "
                        +fDepart+ " " + "INNER JOIN" + " " +sBusSchedule+ " " +
                        "ON " +sBusSchedule+ "." +sBusDate+ "=" +fDepart+ "." 
                        +fDate+ " " + "WHERE " +fDate+ "= '" +fDate1+"'"+" "+
                        "AND" + " " +sBusDepartT+ " " + "= strftime('%H:%M', '" +fTime+ "', '" +getVarMin()+"');");
                cur = fetchAllTodos();

                if (cur.getCount() == 0){
                    switch (Min){
                    case 140 :
                        Min = 145;
                        break;
                    case 145 :
                        Min = 150;
                        break;
                    case 150 :
                        Min = 155;
                        break;
                    case 155 :
                        Min = 180;
                        break;
                    case 200 :
                        mustCont = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }else{
                    mustCont = false;
                }
            }
            if(cur != null && cur.getCount()>0){
                cur.moveToFirst();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), cur.getString(0)+ "  " +cur.getString(1)+ "  "
                             +cur.getString(2)+ "  " +cur.getString(3)+ "\n",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    }
protected void ScheduleOp2(){

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Date selected:"
                 + fDate2 + "\n" +
                "Time Selected:" + fTime2,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


           //fetching records from database
         public  Cursor fetchAllTodos() {   
         return db.query(view_Schedule1, new String [] {sBusDepart, 
                 sBusArrival, sBusDepartT, sBusArrivalT }, null, null, null, null, null);
           }



    }
```

And here is the update on the significant part of the code

```
protected void ScheduleOp1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Cursor cur = null;
            boolean mustCont = true;
            while (mustCont){
                db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " +view_Schedule1);
                db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " +view_Schedule1+ " " +
                        " AS SELECT " +sBusDepart+ "," +sBusArrival+ "," 
                        +sBusDepartT+ "," +sBusArrivalT+ " FROM" + " "
                        +fDepart+ " " + "INNER JOIN" + " " +sBusSchedule+ " " +
                        "ON " +sBusSchedule+ "." +sBusDate+ "=" +fDepart+ "." 
                        +fDate+ " " + "WHERE " +fDate+ "= '" +fDate1+"'"+" "+
                        "AND" + " " +sBusDepartT+ " " + "= strftime('%H:%M', '" +fTime+ "', '" +getVarMin()+"');");
                cur = fetchAllTodos();

                if (cur.getCount() == 0){
                    switch (Min){
                    case 140 :
                        Min = 145;
                        break;
                    case 145 :
                        Min = 150;
                        break;
                    case 150 :
                        Min = 155;
                        break;
                    case 155 :
                        Min = 180;
                        break;
                    case 200 :
                        mustCont = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }else{
                    mustCont = false;
                }
            }
            if(cur != null && cur.getCount()>0){
                cur.moveToFirst();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), cur.getString(0)+ "  " +cur.getString(1)+ "  "
                             +cur.getString(2)+ "  " +cur.getString(3)+ "\n",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    }
```

Hope you guys can help me out. Thx

Comment: Firstly Instead of 'else if(cur.moveToFirst()==false)' you can simply use 'else' because if its not true then it has to be false. Anyways what is the problem you are facing? Your 'VarMin' variable is not changing? Check the value of 'cur.moveToFirst()' by printing in the console.

Comment: Hi, I cant change it to 'else' cause i'm using that in case there arent any information retrieved. is there a better way to quote a condition for a multiple else if statement to keep changing the values in the 'VarMin' attribute if there arent any information found from the previous retrieval? and i've tried to copy and paste the toast from the 'if' statement but i received an exception error.. any suggestion?

Comment: Ok, let's go back to basics.  You say you're searching, but I see no comparisons going on.  What are you searching for/comparing against to define when your search is successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit : I added the code for managing your query**

Something that you could do :

```
private int mMinutes = 145;
protected void ScheduleOp1() {
    Cursor cur = null;
    boolean mustContinue = true  ;
    while(mustContinue){
         db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS " +view_Schedule1);
    db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW " +view_Schedule1+ " " +
            " AS SELECT " +sBusDepart+ "," +sBusArrival+ "," 
            +sBusDepartT+ "," +sBusArrivalT+ " FROM" + " "
            +fDepart+ " " + "INNER JOIN" + " " +sBusSchedule+ " " +
            "ON " +sBusSchedule+ "." +sBusDate+ "=" +fDepart+ "." 
            +fDate+ " " + "WHERE " +fDate+ "= '" +fDate1+"'"+" "+
            "AND" + " " +sBusDepartT+ " " + "= strftime('%H:%M', '" +fTime+ "', '-" +mMinutes+" minute');");
      cur = fetchAllTodos()
        if(cur.getCount()==0){
            mustContinue = true ;
            switch(mMinutes){
            case 145 :
                mMinutes = 150 ;
                break;
            case 150 :
                mMinutes = 155 ;
                break;
            case 200 : //for max value for example
                mustContinue = false ;
                break;
                //etc ....
            }

        }else{
            mustContinue = false ;
        }
    }
    if(cur != null && cur.getCount()>0){
        cur.moveToFirst();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), cur.getString(0)+ "  " +cur.getString(1)+ "  "
                 +cur.getString(2)+ "  " +cur.getString(3)+ "\n",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        mMinutes = 145;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, i've tried using this but the application just hanged. for Cursor cur= null; , is it supposed to be the same 'cur' as the one used for cur.moveToFirst();? i'm kinda confused

Comment: hi, i've tried the code again and it managed to change the int value. but now when i select a time that is does not return any results, the application stales and crashes. it seems that the else statement contains errors. is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you please update your post with your current code that doesn't work ? The code above is not the absolute answer, you must adapt it to what you are looking for ...

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post with an update of the full code as well as the significant part of the code. Right now only the else statement is having problems as it is not able to catch the exception and causes the application to hang and then crash. Any suggestions?

Comment: Something is wrong, maybe because I was not clear at all. The switch method allows you to adjust time if there is no result. So if currently the value is 145 and there is no results, then we continue with 150 ect ... The last step is 200 but you never affect 200 to the variable.  So add `case 180 : mMinutes=200; break` and it will work

Comment: oh wait.. i've noticed a certain problem that happened. right now it can fully function but if i were to pick the wrong time and it displays the text "not found" and right after that if i were to pick the proper time, it would still return back the same saying "not found". any ideas why this happened?

Comment: I just edit the code. See the last else statement. You must reinitialize `mMinutes = 145;`

Comment: hey. I've just realised something, when i select the time to retrieve information for example "10:00" it works perfectly, but if i were to select an earlier time to retrieve for example "8:00" and then try back the previous time which is at "10:00", it seems to display the results shown for "8:00". And it keeps displaying earlier and earlier time results till there's no records found.. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use global variable like `private String VarMin = "-140 minute";` ?

Comment: hey, thx ! i managed to get the values to change but is there a better way to change the condition of the 'else if' statement? cause now my 'else' statement is not working at all..

Comment: If this didn't solve your problems it shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` makes no sense...  Either moveToFirst is true, or it is false (meaning that no records were returned).  Basically, what you have now will **NEVER** show the "Not found" toast.

Due to this it's not clear if you want to show the toast when there is no record, or set the variable.

Either way you should clean up your `if` to something like this (assuming you want the variable set):

```
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
  Toast.makeText(
     getBaseContext(),
     cur.getString(0) + "  " + cur.getString(1) + "  "
     + cur.getString(2) + "  " + cur.getString(3) + "\n",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } else {
     VarMin = "-150 minute";
  }
```

**EDIT**

And the way your code is arranged, you are always going to be putting "-140 Minute" into your database.  If you want the changes made by your IF to get into the database, you need to move it before the db operations.

Comment: hi, i have changed my code and i'm able to change the values in the attribute now but what if i plan to keep changing the values using 'else if' statements? wad condition should i use? cause i would still want to have the 'else' statement to display a toast message in case there are totally no information found at all.

Comment: Wait-a-minute... are you trying to iterate through a cursor with multiple records?  Right now that code only checks/makes changes for the first record (if it exists).  Maybe fully explain what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: i'm currently trying to perform a search through a view i created by combining two different tables together based on the time and date chosen by the user. So far everything works except for the 'VarMin' string attribute which is suppose to represent how many minutes to deduct from the time chosen by the user. Therefore, i need to create multiple 'else if' statements to keep changing the value in 'VarMin' to accommodate the time chosen by the user.

Comment: and the 'VarMin' attribute value is changed whenever the previous one is not able to return any results. and the 'else' statement is for when there are totally no results found after all the 'else if' statements have been run.

Comment: hope you understand what i'm trying to say.